# Concatenar correctamente datos al hacer un select en java a db

Tags: java, mysql, select, jdbc

estuve realizando unas mejoras a mi pequeño sistema y me entra la duda ya que siempre eh realizado concatenados a datos en el where y no después del select, ya que, ahora la duda es concatenar la tabla seleccionada(db) y el pk(dni) ingresado.

Este es mi codigo :3

```
if (txtDniColaborador.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DEBE INGRESAR UN DNI");
    } else {

        tabla = txtTabla.getText();
        dni = txtDniColaborador.getText();
   try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbDaca?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "1234");
        Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = st.executeQuery("SELECT CONCAT("+tabla+") LIKE '%" + tabla + "%' FROM  WHERE CONCAT(DniColaborador) LIKE '%" + dni + "%'");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmt = rst.getMetaData();
        int nrocolumnas = rsmt.getColumnCount();
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        this.jTable1.setModel(modelo);
        for (int x = 1; x <= nrocolumnas; x++) {
            modelo.addColumn(rsmt.getColumnLabel(x));

        }

        while (rst.next()) {
            Object[] fila = new Object[nrocolumnas];

            for (int y = 0; y < nrocolumnas; y++) {
                fila[y] = rst.getObject(y + 1);

            }

            modelo.addRow(fila);

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
        ce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException se) {

        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Ciertamente me tira error, pero esa mi duda no logro concatenar bien mis datos en el preparedStatement. aqui esta cuando voy a probarlo, en el **cbTabla** estan mis 11 tablas que añadi para que el usuario las seleccione la tabla que desea buscar con el pk ingresado, las tablas tienen el mismo nombre en mi bd y son las mismas en donde se ingreso como item en el **cbTabla** para que no haya ningun problema a la hora de concatenar

[image: ejemplo]
Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer. ¿Quieres que el `DNI` se busque en la tabla que sea seleccionada en el ComboBox que aparece antes del botón `Buscar`? ¿Todas esas tablas tienen un campo `dni`?

Comment: Si! Correcto, ya que mi llave primaria esta referenciada en todas las tablas, el campo exactamente es DniColaborador :)

Comment: Entonces tu consulta debería ser así: `"SELECT * FROM "+ tabla +" WHERE DniColaborador = '" + dni + "'";`. Yo usaría **consultas preparadas**,  ya que tu código es vulnerable a **Inyección SQL**. Deberías considerarlo, una vez el código funcione como esperas.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado. Estuve aprendiendo por youtube, y si, stored procedure es mucho mas seguro, definitivamente lo tomare en cuenta. Gracias por la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Bueno en realidad `stored procedure` es otra cosa, yo me refiero a **consultas preparadas**. Si te interesa puedo mostrar una respuesta aplicando esa metodología.

Comment: Aya disculpa, si , si no es mucho pedir :)

Answer (score -1):

Si quieres enviar una consulta que busque el DNI en la tabla seleccionada en el combobox, necesitas escribir una consulta normal que use únicamente la variable `tabla`.

También yo blindaría el código contra los llamados ataques de **Inyección SQL**.  Como norma general, **siempre que recojas datos provenientes desde el exterior**, como es el caso del valor introducido en el textbox, **usa consultas preparadas**.

La Inyección SQL es un grave peligro. Suponte que alguien en vez del DNI solamente escribe algo así:

> **¡PELIGRO!: NO PRUEBES ESTO**
>
> <s>`1 ; DELETE FROM DatosssssFamiliarColaboradorrrr`</s>

Estarías enviando dos consultas, en la segunda se borraría enteramente la tabla `DatosFamiliarColaborador`. Este un ejemplo, de los más *amables*, de lo que puede ocurrir cuando escribes código vulnerable.

En base lo comentado te muestro una respuesta usando consultas preparadas, con ellas la Inyección SQL queda neutralizada.

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM "+ tabla +" WHERE DniColaborador = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conexion.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
ps.setString(1, dni);
ResultSet rst = ps.executeQuery();
```